# SVG text doesn't show up in html file

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have used Figma in order to create some animated text -> right click -> copy as SVG and inserted into an html file, but when I refresh the webpage the text doesnt show up, just a white stripe under the image that already was in the html file. Could you please help me? This is sooo frustrating.

Now, the code of the SVG animation is incredibly long and full of numbers, so I will put it simple for you

```css
@import './birds-animation';
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
     <title>icy-blues</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website1.css">
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta name="description" content="stufffff">
        <meta name="keywords" content="stuff2">
        <meta name="author" content="Ray">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="birds-container">
 
            <div class="bird-container bird-container--one">
                <div class="bird bird--one"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="bird-container bird-container--two">
                <div class="bird bird--two"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="bird-container bird-container--three">
                <div class="bird bird--three"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="bird-container bird-container--four">
                <div class="bird bird--four"></div>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <svg width="850" height="118" viewBox="0 0 850 118" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g filter="url(#filter0_b)">
            <path d="numbersAndLetters" fill="#004756"/>
            then more of these path elements
            </g>
            <defs>
            <filter id="filter0_b" x="-4" y="-4" width="857.902" height="125.083" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="2"/>
            <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"/>
            </filter>
            </defs>
            </svg>
            
       
         
     </body>


 </html>
```

Comment: Sooooo, just a couple things... `content="width=device-width>` is missing the closing quotations, and those "numbers and letters" are required to plot the path data geometry to see the actual SVG so we're not sure what we're trying to see to confirm it's what's expected visually anyway.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know that they are required but it's so long that i'm not even sure if I am allowed to post it in here, I was just trying to give you a rough idea but I will try to put it now. I tried just now but it wouldnt let me since its 382488 characters

Answer (score 0):

This previous SO post had the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57532709/2544629

The fix is to replace

```
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="2"/>
```

with

```
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImageFix" stdDeviation="2"/>
```

Figma seems to incorrectly export this chain of filters. I had the same issue.